# Big Nerd Ranch GeoQuiz - not taken to the cheat activity after clicking the “cheat button” - Chapter 5

Tags: android

I am building the GeoQuiz Android app from the Big Nerd Ranch Guide to Android Development. When I click the "cheat button" the cheat activity is not launched as expected. I'm not sure where I am getting off track.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";

private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;
private Button mNextButton;
private Button mPreviousButton;
private Button mCheatButton;
private TextView mQuestionTextView;

//create array of questions to display to the user
private Question[] mQuestionsBank = new Question[]{
        new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
};

private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

private void updateQuestion(){
    int question = mQuestionsBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue){
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionsBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

    int messageResId = 0;

    if(userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue){
        messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
    }else{
        messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");//add logging from chapter3
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

    //chapter2 page 53 code challenge
    mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionsBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });//end chapter2 page 53 code challenge

    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            checkAnswer(true);
        }
    });

    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionsBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    //chapter2 page 55 code challenge
    mPreviousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1)% mQuestionsBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });//end chapter2 page 55 code challenge

    //chapter5 new activity-setting up onClickListener for the cheat button
    mCheatButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
    mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //Start CheatActivity
            boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionsBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
            Intent i = CheatActivity.newIntent(QuizActivity.this, answerIsTrue);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
    }

    updateQuestion();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    outState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);

}
//override activity lifecycle methods-chapter3
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
} //END override activity lifecycle methods-chapter3

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quiz, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

CheatActivity code:

public class CheatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE =
        "com.exmple.kimcook.qeoquiz.answer_is_true";

private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;
private TextView mAnswerTextView;
private Button mShowAnswer;

public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContent, boolean answerIsTrue){
    Intent i = new Intent(packageContent, CheatActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
    return i;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

    mAnswerIsTrue  = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE,false);
    mAnswerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer_text_view);
    mShowAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show_answer_button);
    mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(mAnswerIsTrue){
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
            }else
            {
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted looks fine.

The issue is most likely somewhere else.

All activities have to be listed in the AndroidManifest.xml.
You might have forgotten to update the manifest, so you should check that.

Feel free to post your AndroidManifest.xml here (If you're not sure about how it works), and we can quickly see if that is the issue.

Comment: Thank you Moonbloom, it is working now all of a sudden.  Thank you again.